# Extract Excel VBA filenames from string

Tags: excel, vba, string, windows, extract

I want to extract file names from a string. The length of the string and the length of the file name are always different.
Must be done with VBA!

String:

href ist gleich: "abc/db://test.pdf|0|100">Bsp.:

I would like that:
test.pdf

I do not know how to proceed.
It would also be nice if the script could extract multiple filenames from a string.

Zb:

String:

```
href ist gleich: "abc//db://test.t.pdf|0|100" "db://test1.pdf|0|100">Bsp.
```

I would like that:

```
test.t.pdf test1.pdf
```

Comment: Does the name always have // before and | after?

Comment: You might use a regex like `db://([^|"\s]+\.pdf)\|` and take the value from capturing group 1. See https://regex101.com/r/QoOiXZ/1

Comment: No another example could be:

 leich: "file://D:/ETVGI_556/Carconfigurator_file/carconf_d.pdf">carconfig

Comment: Then try `/([^/|"\s]+\.pdf)` https://regex101.com/r/rad6lx/1 or `/(\w+\.pdf)` https://regex101.com/r/zb4ISt/1

Comment: Try looking for `.pdf` in the string and then look for a `\` in the string before the `.pdf`..?

Comment: Is the file extension always `.pdf`?  If not, is there a list of file extensions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and edit it according to your needs. At least it was designed for two of your examples.

```
Dim sStringToFormat As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim vSplit As Variant
Dim colFileNames As Collection
Dim sFormattedString As String

Set colFileNames = New Collection

sStringToFormat = "href ist gleich: ""abc//db://test.t.pdf|0|100"" ""db://test1.pdf|0|100"">Bsp."

vSplit = Split(sStringToFormat, "/")

For i = LBound(vSplit) To UBound(vSplit)

    If InStr(vSplit(i), ".") > 0 Then
        sFormattedString = Split(vSplit(i), "|")(0)
        sFormattedString = Split(sFormattedString, "<")(0)
        sFormattedString = Split(sFormattedString, ">")(0)
        colFileNames.Add sFormattedString
    End If

Next i
```

Comment: I do not think he would want to test both strings at ones. I am afraid it was just a bad way of his need definition...

Comment: he needed to return all file names with extensions from string. not only the first match

Comment: I mean you may be right, but I couldn't understand what exactly he needs. I (just) believe that he needs to extract the path from each such a string. A string, not what he presented. But I may be wrong, too... I think, now it is this turn to clarify the issue.

Comment: You probably changed the variable name at the end and you forgot to change `vSplit = Split(s, "/")` in `vSplit = Split(sStringToFormat, "/")`. I think it's good to edit it and correct...

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub testExtractFileName()
 Debug.Print extractFileName("file://D:/ETVGI_556/Carconfigurator_file/carconf_d.pdf", "//")
 Debug.Print extractFileName("abc//db://test.t.pdf|0|100")
 Debug.Print extractFileName("db://test1.pdf|0|100")
End Sub

Function extractFileName(initString As String, Optional delim As String) As String
 Dim necString As String
   necString = left(initString, InStr(initString, ".pdf") + 3)
   necString = Right(necString, Len(necString) - InStrRev(necString, _
            IIf(delim <> "", delim, "/")) - IIf(delim <> "", Len(delim) - 1, 0))
   extractFileName = necString
End Function
```

The single condition is that in front of the file name (all the time) to exist `"//"` characters in the initial string. And of course the file extension to all the time to be `.pdf.` If not, this extension is required and the function can be easily adapted...
The function returns full name if the second (optional) parameter will be `"//"` or just the file name (without path) if it is omitted.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be using a pattern where you would match the preceding `/` and capture in a group 1+ word characters `\w+` followed by `.pdf`

Your value is in capturing group 1.

```
/(\w+\.pdf)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zb4ISt/1)

If you want to have a broader match than `\w` you could extend what you do want to match using a character class or use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^` to match any char except the listed in the character class.

In this case the negated character class `[^/|"\s]` would match any char except `/` `|` `"` or a whitespace character `\s`

```
/([^/|"\s]+\.pdf)
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rad6lx/1)